# In Python, what does [-n:] do?

Tags: python, set

Sorry for the basic question, but what does this mean:

```
active = set(self.go[-self.length:]):
```

Can anyone provide a reference to explain `[-n:]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have negative indices in python, in which case it starts counting backward:

```
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> li[1:]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> li[-3:]
[2, 3, 4]
```

So, `-n` is same as `len(l) - n`, and returns the last `n` elements of the list. Range is rounded to `0`, if indices go out of range.

Note that, you can have out of range indices in slice notation:

```
>>> li[-6:]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> li[:60]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> li[-100:100]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is not the same, when you use index out of range for getting single element:

```
>>> li[-1]
4
>>> li[len(li) - 1]  # Same as previous
4
>>> li[-100]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

[Negative indices count from the end of the list.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Comment: So it counts from the end of the list and splits when it reaches the end?

Comment: "splits"? It's a slice operation; splitting is something else, usually in the context of strings.